# Problem with "has leaked window" on dialog

Tags: android, dialog, broadcastreceiver

I am writing an android app to give the user the option to call a different alternative number based on the number he tried to call.
To do that I have BroadCastReceiver that gets the number being called, checks if there are alternatives and then to show the dialog it starts a new activity to do that as it can not do on its own.
Everything is ok except the activity get closed before the dialog appears, so I get a window leaked exception but I can not see how I can make it works, waiting for the result of the dialog (uncomment the loop in the NumberDialog class) results in no exception but no dialog.

The sources are:

```
package com.frisco.hello;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.frisco.hello.util.DataBaseHelper;

public class Caller extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "HelloWorld";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        String number = getResultData();

        if (intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) && number != null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Recibido evento por el numero" + number);
            DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);         
            try {            
                myDbHelper.createDataBase();             
            } catch (IOException ioe) {          
                throw new Error("Unable to create database");            
            }            
            try {            
                myDbHelper.openDataBase();           
            }catch(SQLException sqle){           
                throw sqle;          
            }
            String[] results = myDbHelper.getAlternateNumbers(number);
            if (results.length > 1) {

                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,
                        Uri.fromParts("com.frisco.hello.number", Uri.decode(number),null));
                number = null;
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);  
            }
        }
    }   

}
```

Number dialog:

```
package com.frisco.hello;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;

import com.frisco.hello.util.DataBaseHelper;

public class NumberDialog extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "HelloWorld"; 
    private CharSequence[] alternates;
    private CharSequence selected = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        String target = uri.getSchemeSpecificPart();
        Log.d(TAG,"Decodificado el numero como "+target);
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);        
        try {            
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();             
        } catch (IOException ioe) {          
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");            
        }            
        try {            
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();           
        }catch(SQLException sqle){           
            throw sqle;          
        }  
        String[] results = myDbHelper.getAlternateNumbers(target);
        alternates = results;
        new AlertDialog.Builder( this)
            .setTitle( "Select number" )
            .setItems( results, new DialogSelectionClickHandler())
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
            .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    finish();
                }
            })          
            .show(); 
/*      while (selected == null) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                ;
            }
        }
        Log.i( TAG, "Seleccionado " + selected );
*/      
    }

    public class DialogSelectionClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener, DialogInterface.OnDismissListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.i( TAG, which+"_"+alternates[which] );
            selected = alternates[which];
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Log.i( TAG, "Dismissed" );
            selected = alternates[0];
        }
    }    
}
```

LogCat

```
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464): Activity com.frisco.hello.NumberDialog has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43e48270 that was originally added here
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.frisco.hello.NumberDialog has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43e48270 that was originally added here
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at com.frisco.hello.NumberDialog.onCreate(NumberDialog.java:56)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-29 17:52:28.309: ERROR/WindowManager(4464):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: First of all you probably don't need to do `import com.frisco.hello.util.DataBaseHelper;`

Comment: Indeed I need to, I am using and extended class from DatabaseHelper that adds custom querys as `myDbHelper.getAlternateNumbers(target);`

Comment: What does that have to do with importing a class from the same package?

Comment: I see your point but it is under the util subpackage so you need to import it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I can not activate other Activity while in the phone call process.
But that was not what I was trying, stopping the current call showing a dialog and then starting a new one with different number.
So the fix is as simple as changing on the Caller class:
`number = null;` 
for
`setResultData(null);`
which indeed ends the calls and allow my new activity to show its dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
new AlertDialog.Builder( this)
            .setTitle( "Select number" )
            .setItems( results, new DialogSelectionClickHandler())
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
            .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    finish();
                }
            })          
            .create().show();
```